# how i can get the column value of admin user table in magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, column, admin-user

> Hi I have created a new column in the admin users table
>
> using this answers [Magento2: How to add new column in admin_user table?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/277685/73525)
>
> Now **I want to get the column value when admin user logged in**

How i can get this?

Comment: My solution is working for you? let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: i will check @ChiragPatel bro....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject `UserModel` class to your construct and you can fetch details.

```
protected $userFactory;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\User\Collection $userCollection,
    ...
)
{
    ...
    $this->userCollection = $userCollection;
    ...
}

public function getUserData()
{
    $user = $this->userCollection->create();
    print_r($user->getData);
}
```

For apply condition is customer is logged in or not you can check from customer session.

Inject `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session` in your cunstruct and get value using `$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()`

I hope it helps!

Comment: can i use in controller

Comment: You can use a block as well controller where you want to get data.

Comment: Just remove `->create` and see.

Comment: how i can get the logged in user details

i'm getting all users data

Comment: If can get using resource model collection & model class factory. But if you are using resource model collection then you don't need to use `->create()`

Comment: I have already post in answer To get logged in user detail use `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session`

Comment: hooo   ok ................

Comment: For user, collection see this reference link https://www.amitmerchant.com/get-all-admin-users-as-array-magento2/

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation answer ;) +1 for your appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried this works for me

need to add this to the constructor of your class

```
protected $authSession;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession, 
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->authSession = $authSession;
    ....
}
```

Then create this method

```
public function getCurrentUser()
{
    return $this->authSession->getUser();
}
```

this will give you the current logged in admin.

You can later get the details like $user->getUsername() or $user->getEmail().